# How do you set select date in class CreateView (django.views.generic) for deadline?

Tags: python, django, django-generic-views

I can select date for deadline if I creating gig in admin, but when user creates a new gig the datefield doesn't work in the form and I don't know how to set it. Can someone help?

**views.py**

```
class GigCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Gig
    template_name = 'gigs/create_gig.html'
    fields = ['title',
     'industry', 
     'city', 
     'country', 
     'gigdescription', 
     'deadline',
     ]
```

**create_gig.html**

```
                <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    {% csrf_token %}

                    <fieldset class="form-group">
                        <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Create Gig</legend>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h6 class="card-text">Title: &nbsp; {{form.title}}</h6>
                            <h6 class="card-title">Profession: &nbsp; {{form.profession}}</h6>
                            <h6 class="card-title">City: &nbsp; {{form.city}}</h6>
                            <h6 class="card-text">Deadline: &nbsp; {{form.deadline}}</h6>
                            <h6 class="card-text">Description: &nbsp; {{form.gigdescription}}</h6>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>

                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                        <!-- Edit button -->
                        <div class="form-group col-3 text-center">
                            <button class="btn btn-edit" type="submit">UPDATE</button>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Delete button -->
                        <div class="form-group col-3 text-center">
                            <button class="btn btn-delete" type="#">DELETE</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </form>
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You are getting text input instead of date picker for `deadline` field?

Answer (score 0):

Just added date input the widgets in form:

```
class GigForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Gig
        fields = [
            'title',
            'industry',
            'profession',
            'city',
            'country',
            'gigdescription',
            'extrainfo',
            'author',
            'deadline',
        ]
        widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'industry': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'profession': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),

            'city': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'country': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'author': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),

            'gigdescription': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'extrainfo': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'deadline': forms.DateInput(
                format=('%Y-%m-%d'), attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control', 
                    'placeholder': 'Select a date',
                    'type': 'date'
                }),
        }
```